# Can anyone decipher this error message?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, iats

I've installed civiCRM on a new site using iATS as the payment processor. I've only used payments for Events. Now I am creating my first contribution page. It loads fine, goes to a confirmation page. When I click on the submit button (expecting a thank you) everything blows up with the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in evaluated template line 54]: syntax error: (secure mode) 'd' not allowed in if statement (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1399) in /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1100
There has been a critical error on this website.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sg-security/templates/error.php:111
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sg-security/core/Helper/Helper.php(111): include() 
#1 /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(3713): SG_Security\Helper\Helper->custom_wp_die_callback(Object(WP_Error), '', Array) 
#2 /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(234): wp_die(Object(WP_Error), '', Array) 
#3 /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(153): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, Object(WP_Error)) 
#4 /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(57): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, Object(WP_Error)) 
#5 [in in /home/customer/www/my_website.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sg-security/templates/error.php on line 111
```

---

Should have mentioned that I am using a one-page WordPress theme and civiCRM 5.53

Comment: Is your contribution receipt message template customized? There might be a code error or a stray `{` or `}`. Try reverting to the default template.

Comment: No. Just a simple sentence with "tax-deductible" Does the hyphen need to be escaped? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Where exactly is the sentence - is it in between a `{` and a `}`? If you move it somewhere else does it change anything?

Comment: There are no { or }. The entire receipt message is: "This is your receipt for your donation which is tax-deductible. Please keep this receipt with your tax records."

Comment: Is the contribution message template at `/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1&selectedChild=workflow` customized?

Comment: I found two messageTemplates files: one in Form and one in Page. I assume we are dealing with the Form folder. I did not intentionally edit this file. I should add that the financial transaction went through but the donor did not receive a confirmation email. I was thinking of creating a new Contribution page but I guess if the messageTemplate is corrupted a new page would not work either.

Comment: I meant in the browser at the url above. Or from the civi menu Administer - CiviMail - Message Templates.

Comment: We need to see the smarty used for the error page.

Comment: JohnFF: what is the smarty?

Comment: The contribution message template was NOT customized. The problem does not happen every time. Just some of the time (????). #Demerit